# Libtorrent : declared deprecated error

Tags: c++, libtorrent

The following line :

`p.ti = new torrent_info(argv[1], ec);`

shows the below error :

`error C4996: 'libtorrent::torrent_info::torrent_info': was declared deprecated`

How may I resolve this?

Comment: what program are you using?

Comment: Simple failure to read the documentation. Doesn't seem like you even looked it up, to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the comments in `torrent_info.hpp`?

```
    // all wstring APIs are deprecated since 0.16.11
    // instead, use the wchar -> utf8 conversion functions
    // and pass in utf8 strings
```

You should therefore convert your wide-character argv[1] into UTF-8 using the functions provided by libtorrent, then construct your torrent_info from that.

Comment: Thankyou i did a `(wchar*)` casting of the variable that resolved the error. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This message is usually only a warning, maybe you have a flag to treat warnings as errors. Try to remove `/WX` compiler flag, `Treat Warnings as Errors` option  , or disable this specific warning by adding this flag, or option: `/wd 4996`. [More info on MSVC warning flags...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y.aspx)

Comment: Treat all warnings as errors is disabled ie I have `/WX-`